# How to pass UIViewController instance to Custom UITableCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller which is HomeController.I added a tableview in my HomeController.I added a Custom cell on this `UITableView` which name is HomeCategoryRow. So my search is I have to pass HomeController instance to my `HomeCategoryRow` class for my work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"The View Controller is: %@",_homeController); 
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
AblumsController *myAlbum = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumsControllerIdentifier"]; // myAlbum.typeofParam=2; 
myAlbum.homeController = _homeController;//ADD THIS
[_homeController pushViewController:myAlbum animated:YES];
```

**AblumsController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id homeController;
```

or

```
@class HomeController;
@interface HomeTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) HomeController *homeController;
```

**AblumsController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HomeCategoryRow *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.homeController = self.homeController
}
```

**HomeCategoryRow.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id homeController;
```

or

```
@class HomeController;
@interface HomeCategoryRow : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) HomeController *homeController;
```

**HomeCategoryRow.m**

```
#import "HomeController.h"
```

Comment: NSLog(@"The View Controller is: %@",_homeController);
   
  
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    AblumsController *myAlbum = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumsControllerIdentifier"];
  //  myAlbum.typeofParam=2;
    
    [_homeController pushViewController:myAlbum animated:YES];                      //I am using the instance variable to go another view controller ......But still showing  as i printed The View Controller is: (null)

Comment: `AblumsController *myAlbum` is tableview in your `HomeController`?

Comment: I am using homeController instance to  go new uiviewcontroller i.e:    [_homeController pushViewController:myAlbum animated:YES];   But not working

Comment: No this is another viewController @tim007

Comment: myAlbum.homeController = _homeController; How it will work ?I am not using homeController instance in AblumsController. I don't need so.                 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
AblumsController *myAlbum = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumsControllerIdentifier"]; // myAlbum.typeofParam=2; 
myAlbum.homeController = _homeController;//ADD THIS
[_homeController pushViewController:myAlbum animated:YES];  this code i am using in my HomeCategoryRow.m class

Comment: you may post sample project https://github.com/larsblumberg/selection-test ,it's easier to understand your code.

Comment: Thank you so much ....Solved my problem by following code : UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    AblumsController *myAlbum = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumsControllerIdentifier"];
       myAlbum.typeofParam=2;
    _myHomeController=_homeController;
    
    [_myHomeController.navigationController pushViewController:myAlbum animated:YES];